# C# Unpacking Dictionary<string, List<string>>

Tags: c#, dictionary, var, unpack

Quick (and dumb) question on the proper unpacking of a dictionary
which format is `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.

When I try to unpack it using `foreach` with the code below:

`foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> item in _results)`

I do not have access to `item.Key` or `item.Value`. I only have them as a group with `item.Keys` or `item.Values`.

However, I know its possible to get that access because currently I'm using:

`foreach (var item in _results)`

and I can access `item.Key` and `item.Value`.

Whats the proper way to unpack without using `var`?

Comment: Could you share a code sample? Your code is supposed to work. https://dotnetfiddle.net/weYM3a

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are doing wrong without you showing any more code (it _should_ work). But, what's wrong with using `var`? The code is easier to read that way anyway. Are you just asking to satisfy some curiosity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach to loop through your dictionary:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Exercise
{
    static class Program
    {
        static public void Main()
        {
            var _results = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>{{"a", new List<string>{"x", "y", "z"}}, {"b", new List<string>{"x", "y"}}, {"c", new List<string>{"x"}}, };
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> item in _results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}: {item.Value.Count}");
                foreach (var s in item.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/IGwkuU

Comment: This looks like the way to get them to unpack. Unfortunately I guess it cant do it as simply as say in Python. Good to know. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through a dictionary using the 'Keys' property and then you can access the value via an index.

e.g.

```
foreach (var key in _results.Keys)
{
    var value = _results[key];
}
```